# Read pcap.gz file in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gzip, pcap

I have a ~ 500gb pcap.gz file that I would like to read using node.js. I tried using wireshark to export this file as JSON however it took about an hour and resulted in a 47 gb file (far to large to be practical). I eventually hunted down a node module that can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap-parser) that should be able to read pcap files. Then I used 7zip to extract the pcap file (resulting in a file a little over a 2 gigabytes) and tried to run this code:

```
var pcapp = require('pcap-parser');

var parser = pcapp.parse('C:/Users/.../data.pcap');
parser.on('packet', function(packet) {
    console.log(packet);
});
```

and got the following error code

```
events.js:182

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: unknown magic number: 0a0d0d0a
```

What would be ideal for me would be a node.js script that could parse pcap.gz files such that I would not have to go through any intermediary application such as wireshark or 7zip.

Here is a download link for the file: [download](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/iex/o/data%2Ffeeds%2F20170802%2F20170802_IEXTP1_TOPS1.5.pcap.gz?generation=1501718775293088&alt=media)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the NPM pcap parser on some pcap files I made myself with Wireshark and it works fine with both .pcap and .pcap.gz. However the pcap file in question was apparently not a pcap file but rather a pcap-ng file as demonstrated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222047/weird-pcap-header-of-byte-sequence-0a-0d-0d-0a-created-on-mac). The solution was then load my pcap-ng file in wireshark and save it with the tcpdump library. After having done this the NPM pcap parser parsed the file just fine. I realize this is not a perfect solution as I still have to go through wireshark but it is a start.